# Adjective ‘Half’ & past participle ‘halved’

Tags: adjectives, determiners, past-participles

When is adjective or determiner *Half* used and, when is past participle modifier *halved* used attributively?

Answer (score 2):

We don't normally use ***halved*** adjectivally - it's far more common as the past participle of the verb ***to halve** = to reduce something to half of what it was OR to divide something into two halves*.

There are a few contexts where it's used as an adjective - [for example...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=halved%20walnuts%2Chalf%20walnuts%2Chalf-walnuts&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalved%20walnuts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chalf%20walnuts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chalf%20-%20walnuts%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...but *in general* it's probably better to just use ***half*** (with or without the optional hyphen before the actual noun being modified) unless you're simply repeating a usage from a native speaker. In any context where you might consider using ***halved walnuts***, for example, it would never be "invalid" to use ***half[-]walnuts***.

---

Note that using the Past Tense verb form ***halved*** adjectivally calls more attention to *the **earlier act** of halving [which led to the current state]*, whereas the "flat" form ***half*** focuses on the ***current state*** itself (regardless of how it came to be like that).

---

*Also* note that most things which might be adjectivally modified to indicate "half" were never "reduced" from an original "whole" anyway *(half-brother = step-brother, score a half-century in snooker, a half-size guitar,...)*, where past participle ***halved*** would never be appropriate.